# How do I select All Great-Grandchildren elements in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a way to select jquery elements based on their "generation"? For example, selecting all great-grandchildren of an element?

This is obviously wrong, but this is my line of thinking:
`$('#mydiv' :4th-generation').click();`

I couldn't find anything in the jQuery docs or here at SO about it...

**UPDATE:** based on suggested results below, here's a working proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/eZhEM/

Thanks for the guys who replied!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this I suppose (untested):

```
$('#mydiv > * > * > *').whatever();
```

Comment: perfect! thanks. I updated the question with a working fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s one way: `$("#mydiv > * > * > * > *")`. (You could obviously write a helper function if you wanted to be able to pass in an arbitrary integer.)

Comment: good thinking about the helper function, i'll have to make a note of that!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what exactly you are looking for, but maybe this:?

```
$('#mydiv').children().children().children().children().click(function(e){
 alert('sds'); });
```